# gdb on Yosemite: SIGBUS error when calling function at gdb command line

Tags: c, debugging, emacs, gdb, osx-yosemite

I am using GDB to debug a program on Yosemite OSX. At a breakpoint, I want to print out some information using an internal function, but I get a SIGBUS error even with a trivial function. For example:

```
Breakpoint 1, ...
(gdb) print my_info_function()
Program received signal SIGBUS, Bus error.
<function called from gdb>
The program being debugged was signaled...
```

where `my_info_function` is:

```
const char *my_info_function() {
  return "hello";
}
```

In addition, if I run the program with gdb, then interrupt it while it is running, then, regardless of whether the interruption occurs before or after the above breakpoint, `print my_info_function()` works fine.

This problem seemed to start occurring after upgrading to Yosemite (from Lion), so I am inclined to think it is related to that. I tried using different compilers (clang, gcc-4.9, brew vs macports), and using / reinstalling / rebuilding different gdb's (brew, macports, as well as [this brew gdb version](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ymyzk/10ad2b74af9235eddb2c/raw/c658d0f0537a31accfb6bd9f0fd878498b237245/gdb.rba)), all to no avail.

Any suggestions as to how to fix this? I am using emacs + gdb and would like to keep it that way. I'd probably be fine with emacs + lldb, but it seems there is some debate over whether/when that will be supported.

Comment: Does it work stepping through `main`? Or just when you call a function?

Comment: Works when main first starts and before it multithreads. On closer look, it seems only reproducible when the breakpoint is triggered at code running on a child thread. For what it is worth, the same debugging exercise in lldb acts as expected (no problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any suggestions as to how to fix this?

This looks like a bug in GDB.

You can either try to build GDB from source, debug GDB with itself, and send a patch to the [gdb-patches mailing list](https://sourceware.org/ml/gdb-patches/), or just report it in [GDB bugzilla](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=gdb) (and hope that someone else fixes it).